# How to inject service manager into a Model file in Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-servicemanager

I just upgraded one project to Zend Framework 3 from ZF 1.x version.

In ZF 1.x version, we have implemented a functionality like provided an unique id for a request being made in the application using Zend Registry component, which is not there in ZF 3. I am trying to achieve that functionality using ServiceManager.

So I tried to inject ServiceManager to a Model file by creating a Factory class as below:

My Model Class File code:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Model\Common;

use Application\Model\Common\Config\BaseConfig;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;

class CommonUtils  extends BaseConfig{    

    public function __construct(ServiceManager $sm) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($sm);
        exit();
    }

}

?>
```

Factory Class Code:

```
namespace Application\Model\Common;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;

class CommonUtilsFactory implements FactoryInterface{
    //put your code here
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, mixed $options = null) {
        $serviceManager = $container->get('ServiceManager');
        return new CommonUtils($serviceManager);
    }
}
```

Updated module.config.php file as below:

```
    /** SERVICE MANAGER CONFIGURATION - STARTS HERE **/
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            CommonUtils::class => \Application\Model\Common\CommonUtilsFactory::class
        ],

        // Make an alias so that we can use it where we need
        'aliases' => [
        ],
    ],
    /** SERVICE MANAGER CONFIGURATION - ENDS HERE **/
```

But it is NOT working and giving below error.

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Model\Common\CommonUtils::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager, none given

Someone please help me here to understand how to access/ inject ServiceManager in Model file in Zend Framework 3.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your case, `$serviceManager = $container;` but it isn't recommended to pass the entire servicemanager. Instead, inject the objects or services you need.